# How can i query on embedded document using Spring data mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

My document structure looks like

```
{
   "users":[
            {
           "email":"user@company.com"            
            "messages":[
                        {
                          "id":"1",
                          "text":"A",
                          "from":"Jessy",
                          "isDeleted":"false"  
                        },{
                          "id":"2",
                          "text":"B",
                          "from":"Jessy",
                          "isDeleted":"false"  
                        },{
                          "id":"3",
                          "text":"C",
                          "from":"Alan",
                          "isDeleted":"false"  
                        },{
                          "id":"4",
                          "text":"D",
                          "from":"Amy",
                          "isDeleted":"true"  
                        },{
                          "id":"5",
                          "text":"E",
                          "from":"Amy",
                          "isDeleted":"false"  
                        }

            ]            

            }
    ]  

}
```

I want to query on sub document using or & and operations.So my query can be as follow.

select all those messages from the users collection having from as "Amy" and text is "E" or some other Criteria.

I have an idea about the Aggregation Framework supported by Spring data

```
AggregationOperation match =Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("from").is("Amy").and("text").is("E"));

AggregationOperation unwind = Aggregation.unwind("messages");

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(match);

AggregationResults<User> result = this.mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "users", User.class);
```

But my problem is that i want to dynamically populate the Criteria like Criteria is at clients end he or she can pass any query to the database i gonna parse that query into Criteria. Any help will be appreciated.